# Count the number of times the watchdog timer has been reset

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

- Board: MSP-EXP432P401R
- MCU:   MSP432P401R

How do I count the number of times the watchdog timer has been reset?
Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: An appropriate solution will be system specific and you have provided no details. For what MCU?

Comment: MSP-EXP432P401R

Comment: Thanks, but you need to place that information in the question, not a comment.  SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.  Also you need to include unambiguous requirements such as whether the count must be non-volatile (i.e. retained through a power fail).

Comment: ... also MSP-EXP432P401R describes the board, not the MCU - that would be MSP432P401R.  It is important in order that you are reading the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Write code to detect that a watchdog reset has occurred.  The microcontroller may have a register flag that indicates the reason for the previous reset (e.g., hard, soft, brown-out, watchdog, etc.).  Look for this register flag in the reset or power control registers in your microcontroller's reference manual.  Read this register flag during system initialization to detect that a watchdog reset occurred.  Or alternately, enable the watchdog reset interrupt handler to detect that a watchdog reset is occurring.

When a watchdog reset is detected, increment a counter variable and save the counter value to nonvolatile memory.  Read/restore the watchdog counter value from nonvolatile memory during system initialization or before incrementing the count.  Saving the count value in nonvolatile memory allows the count value to be remembered through a power loss.

Comment: Some MCUs also guarantee that RAM values are preserved after a "soft" reset, in which case a reserved RAM chunk can be used instead of NVM.

Comment: @Lundin  In this case (late information from OP in a comment), the MCU in question applies specific technical meaning to "hard" and "soft" reset and the watchdog can perform either (in fact it enumerates four classes of reset POR, Reboot, hard and Soft). The SRAM is preserved through a "hard" watchdog reset in this case (as opposed to a power-on or reboot reset).  I think both "hard" and "soft" reset modes probably count as "soft" in your intended meaning of the term perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

TI don't make it easy to find the documentation!  The MSP432FR401 datasheet has a broken link to the reference manual. I can only find copies at various non-TI sites such as [this](https://schaumont.dyn.wpi.edu/ece4703b21/_downloads/8bf98313124444641502c686bb90dbaa/msp432p401r-trm.pdf). YMMV.

Section 3.3.2 and 3.3.5 describe the hard and soft reset status registers respectively.  The one you need depends on how you have configured the watchdog timer (section 4.11.3).

The reset sources are device specific and not explicitly stated in the general user manual.  It refers you to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas826e/slas826e.pdf).  Unfortunately as far as I can find, the promised information is not there either!  I suggest that you experiment and read the register on start-up following a reset and determine which bit is unique to a watchdog reset rather than say a power-on reset.  (To be honest however I'd also suggest not using a part so poorly documented and supported).

If you can determine which `RSTCTL_HARDRESET_STAT`/`RSTCTL_SOFTRESET_STAT` bit relates specifically to a watchdog reset, you can test it on start-up and increment your counter.  Neither your board or MCU have any convenient non-volatile storage for such a counter.  If you only need to count watchdog resets whilst continuously powered, you can keep the counter in a reserved location in SRAM (a specific address not initialised on start-up and not available to the linker to locate data objects), but if you want a "lifetime" count, then you may need to dedicate an entire 4K flash sector to the counter (and deal with the flash endurance issue - that probably warrants a new question if it is relevant).